Can I set nofile limit to unlimited?
Can I add line of code inside /etc/security/limits.conf which sets nofile limit to unlimited/max value - root - nofile unlimited instead of typing max value like this: root - nofile 1048576 ?
Ubuntu version: 22.04.3 LTS

The most up to date version of Ubuntu 22.04 will read 22.04.4, You appear to need to run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade

According to man limits.conf: "All items support the values -1, unlimited or infinity indicating no limit, except for priority, nice, and nonewprivs. If nofile is to be set to one of these values, it will be set to the contents of /proc/sys/fs/nr_open instead (see setrlimit(3))." On my 24.04 VM, cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open returns 1048576 anyhow.
